# Grid and ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle in WIndows Phone

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, mvvm, grid

I've got a serious problem and i can't solve it. There is the following code what perfectly works in WPF:

```
    <ItemsControl Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding GameFields}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <UniformGrid Rows="7" Columns="7" Margin="20" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button Command="{Binding SingleStepCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Index}" Visibility="{Binding Visible}" Background="Transparent" 
                        Margin="10" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="0">
                    <Button.Content>
                        <Image Source="{Binding IconPath}" Stretch="Fill" />
                    </Button.Content>                            
                </Button>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style>
                <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="{Binding X}" />
                <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="{Binding Y}" />
            </Style>
        </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>            
    </ItemsControl>
```

And a try to implement in Windows Phone(7.1). But all elements of the itemspaneltemplate grid are on each other, i mean on the same X and Y position. Here's what i've tried:

```
    <ItemsControl x:Name="ContentSource" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0" ItemsSource="{Binding GameFields}" >
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RenderTransform>
                        <TransformGroup>
                            <TranslateTransform X="{Binding X}" Y="{Binding Y}" />
                        </TransformGroup>
                    </Grid.RenderTransform>
                </Grid>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>                
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button Command="{Binding SingleStepCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Index}" Visibility="{Binding Visible}" Grid.Row="{Binding X}"
                        Grid.Column="{Binding Y}">
                    <Button.Content>
                        <Image Source="{Binding IconPath}" Stretch="Fill" />
                    </Button.Content>
                </Button>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>             
        <!--ItemsControl.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="17" />
                <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="17" />
            </Style>
        </ItemsControl.Resources-->            
    </ItemsControl>
```

3 different way and none of them works. (Resources, TranslateTransform and Button grid.row binding). Do you have any suggestion what im doing wrong or what should i use?
I have to use MVVM strictly, so there's no code behind. Any advice will get thanks and sorry for my english :)

Comment: Could you please check x,y positions of your GameFields items and validate that they do not have the same value?

Comment: I use the same viewmodel for both solution and in wpf it works perfectly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have got the right idea - you do need to set the Grid.Row and Grid.Column properties on the ContentPresenter. The easiest way to do this is with your own Attached Properties for each.

Something like this:

```
public class ItemsGridLayout
{
    public static int GetGridRow(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (int)obj.GetValue(GridRowProperty);
    }

    public static void SetGridRow(DependencyObject obj, int value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(GridRowProperty, value);
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for GridRow.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty GridRowProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("GridRow", typeof(int), typeof(FrameworkElement), new PropertyMetadata(0, (s, e) =>
        {
            var presenter = GetItemsPresenter(s);
            if (presenter != null)
            {
                Grid.SetRow(presenter, GetGridRow(s));
            }
        }));

    public static int GetGridColumn(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (int)obj.GetValue(GridColumnProperty);
    }

    public static void SetGridColumn(DependencyObject obj, int value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(GridColumnProperty, value);
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for GridColumn.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty GridColumnProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("GridColumn", typeof(int), typeof(FrameworkElement), new PropertyMetadata(0, (s, e) =>
        {
            var presenter = GetItemsPresenter(s);
            if (presenter != null)
            {
                Grid.SetColumn(presenter, GetGridColumn(s));
            }
        }));

    static FrameworkElement GetItemsPresenter(DependencyObject target)
    {
        while (target != null)
        {
            if (target is ContentPresenter)
            {
                return target as FrameworkElement;
            }
            target = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(target);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Then in XAML it's used like this:

```
<ItemsControl>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button local:ItemsGridLayout.GridRow="{Binding X}" 
                    local:ItemsGridLayout.GridColumn="{Binding Y}"
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. However, i found an other solution: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2009/11/02/as-the-platform-evolves-so-do-the-workarounds-better-settervaluebindinghelper-makes-silverlight-setters-better-er.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the very same problem today. Learning Silverlight after WPF, I didn't expect that *this* wouldn't work.

After a few more searches to avoid this kind of workaround, I tried to add a `Style` resource for the `ContentPresenter` and it worked like a charm in Silverlight 5.

```
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource CVM}, Path=PagedItems}">
        <ItemsControl.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="{Binding OffsetX}"/>
                <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="{Binding OffsetY}"/>
            </Style>
        </ItemsControl.Resources>
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                        ...
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                        ...
                        <RowDefinition/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                </Grid>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    </ItemsControl>
```